# Session is disappearing

Tags: php, session, cookies, twitter, oauth

I am using Abraham William's Twitter oAuth library.

Following is my code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token'])){
  print_r($_SESSION);
  exit;
}
/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);     
/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);
/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    print "<script>self.location='$url';</script>";
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
    return;
}
```

If I check for the $_SESSION right before the redirect, $_SESSION is there. When the redirect occurs, $_REQUEST['oauth_token'] is set (I verified this), but the $_SESSION no longer exists.

My browser is set to accept cookies and third party cookies. Any ideas?

Comment: The library I am calling handles that. In my question, I mention that I am testing for the $_SESSION before the re-direct, and the $_SESSION and $_SESSION variables set by the code up to that point are there.

Comment: Why would anyone downgrade my question? I have tags clearly identifying this as a Twitter OAuth issue, using a particular library.

Comment: I had a similar problem when my web directory ran out of space. Try df -h to check the available space and free some up if it's full.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have session_start(); at the top of your page. session_start() is required BEFORE your code uses any session variables.

Comment: The library I am calling handles that. In my question, I mention that I am testing for the $_SESSION before the re-direct, and the $_SESSION and $_SESSION variables set by the code up to that point are there.

Comment: But it looks like you're calling the library after you've tried to access the session variable? If the library starts the session, you won't be able to access any session variables until after it has been included.

Comment: This script is the callback URL for Twitter oAuth. The code upfront gets executed on the re-direct, which happens properly, but the session is disappearing. Please see the tags for this question, and the description upfront (that I'm using the Abraham Williams oAuth library)